# error: Storage location can only be given for array or struct types

Tags: solidity, memory

Getting the error "Storage location can only be given for array or struct types" in a setup function. The exact line is

```
uint memory _total = 0;
```

I'm confused by the error, because I'm not trying to use storage, I'm trying to use memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term "storage location" is a bit misleading here, it refers to a more general concept about where data is stored, i.e. in storage or in memory. The error occurs because the "storage location" is only relevant for reference types like structs and arrays and uints are always passed by value, so you cannot hold a reference to a uint in memory or storage. If you want to do that, you have to create a struct data type that only contains a uint.

Answer (score 2):

"For almost all types, you cannot specify where they should be stored"

"local variables of value type (i.e. neither array, nor struct nor mapping) are stored in the stack"

source: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/frequently-asked-questions.html

So you can not set storage location for uint